# How to Override React Component's Styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, semantic-ui

### How can I override a React Child Component's Styles from global styling?

- I have a Main component custom styled in SCSS
- And I have a child component inside which uses `Semantic-UI-React`
- Now the child component is not able to properly display the styling done by `Semantic-UI-React`

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Here is the code: (stripped down version)

```js
// MainComponent.js

import './styles'

export default class MainComponent extends Component{
 return (
  <Fragment>
   <Some_local_elements /> 
   <ChildComponent />
  </Fragment>
 )
}
```

```js
// ChildComponent.js

import {Menu, Accordian, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class ChildComponent extends Component{
 render(){
  return (
   <Accordian>
    <Accordian.Title
    active={0}
    index={0}
    onClick={this.handleClick}
    >
     <Icon name="dropdown" />
     Experience
    </Accordian.Title>
    <Accordian.Content active={0}>
     {this.state.checkBoxData
      ? this.state.checkBoxData.map((data, index) => {
        return (
         <Menu.Item key={index}>
          <Checkbox key={data.id} label={data.name} value={data.value} />
          <br />
         </Menu.Item>
        )
       }
      ): null}
    <Accordian.Content>
   </Accordian>
  )

 }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to import the semantic-ui css in your main index.html file?

Comment: if the below answers your question give it a green tick and possibly an upvote!!!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
style={{<html DOM attributes with camelcase>}}
```

inside the element you want to give inline styling.

or like this:

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};
function exmaple() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>element</div>;
```